# Elasticsearch: Transpose and aggregate the data

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation, transpose

I am using the ES 6.5. When I fetch the required messages, I have to transpose and aggregate it. See example for more details.

Message retrieved - 2 messages retried for example:

```
{
    "_index": "index_name",
    "_type": "data",
    "_id": "data_id",
    "_score": 5.0851293,
    "_source": {
        "header": {
            "id": "System_20190729152502239_57246_16667",
            "creationTimestamp": "2019-07-29T15:25:02.239Z",
        },
        "messageData": {
            "messageHeader": {
                "date": "2019-06-03",
                "mId": "1000",
                "mDescription": "TEST",
            },
            "messageBreakDown": [
                {
                    "category": "New",
                    "subCategory": "Sub",
                    "messageDetails": [
                        {
                            "Amount": 5.30
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
},
{
    "_index": "index_name",
    "_type": "data",
    "_id": "data_id",
    "_score": 5.09512,
    "_source": {
        "header": {
            "id": "System_20190729152502239_57246_16667",
            "creationTimestamp": "2019-07-29T15:25:02.239Z",
        },
        "messageData": {
            "messageHeader": {
                "date": "2019-06-03",
                "mId": "1000",
                "mDescription": "TEST",
            },
            "messageBreakDown": [
                {
                    "category": "Old",
                    "subCategory": "Sub",
                    "messageDetails": [
                        {
                            "Amount": 4.30
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Now I am looking for a query to post on ES which will transpose the data and group by on category and sub category .

[image: Data output]

So basically if you check the messages, they have same header.id (which is the main search criteria). Within this header.id, one message is for category New and other Old (messageData.messageBreakDown is array and in it category value).

So ideally as you see the output, both messages belong to same mId, and it has New price and Old Price.

- How to aggregate for the desired results ?
- Final output message can have desired fields only e.g. date, mId, mDesciption, New price and Old price (both in one output)?

**UPDATE:**
Below is the mapping,

```
{"index_name":{"mappings":{"data":{"properties":{"header":{"properties":{"id":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"creationTimestamp":{"type":"date"}}},"messageData":{"properties":{"messageBreakDown":{"properties":{"category":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"messageDetails":{"properties":{"Amount":{"type":"float"}}},"subCategory":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}}}},"messageHeader":{"properties":{"mDescription":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"mId":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"date":{"type":"date"}}}}}}}}}}
```

Comment: Could you please post the mapping? Thanks!!

Comment: Updated the original question with the mapping.